# Impossible date issue with formatDate formula

Tags: google-apps-script

I have written a simple function to track payments, and as part of the function want to keep track of the last amount paid and the date the last payment was made within a single cell.

In order to do this, I used the formatDate formula so that the date entered via a date picker would appear in the DD/MM/YY format.

For some reason, the dates entered via the date picker are not working properly with the formatDate formula. For example the date 10/2/20 (10th Feb 2020) is being returned as 41/2/20 and 20/2/20 (20th Feb 2020) is being returned as 51/2/20.

Obviously, it seems like the formula is somehow adding 31 to the dates entered, but I would like some help understanding where I am going wrong.

Here is a picture of the code for my addPayment function: 
[addPayment function code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eTAbt.png)

Comment: I believe the format you want is “dd/MM/yy”

Comment: Kindly [edit] to include the code as text. See [ask]

Comment: Could you please share a sample of your spreadsheet so that we can see more clearly what is going on in the script and in the sheet? Also, what are you passing in the ```cell``` parameter for the function? Are you using correctly the SpreadhseetApp service?

Comment: I apologize for the improper formatting on my part, but wanted to confirm that the suggestion from Cooper above worked. After changing the code from "dd/mm/yy" to "dd/MM/yy" the dates are being applied correctly. 

Thank you Cooper and thanks as well to the other commenters who sought to help

Comment: Could you or @Cooper then post what did work as an answer so that anyone reaching this question can clearly see the solution?

Answer (score 1):

It was suggested to that Utilities.formatDate() was not working with the format string of “DD/MM/YY” and I simply suggested to try “dd/MM/yy”